# How to delete users who have not added card?

Tags: sql, mysql, left-join, sql-delete

I have the following query:

```
select u.*
from users u
left join customers_cards cc
  on cc.user_id = u.id
where u.belongs_to = "ezpay"
  and cc.id is null
```

It returns users who have not added any card yet. I need to delete these users (from `users`) table. So here is my `delete` query:

```
delete from users
where id in ( select u.id
              from users u
              left join customers_cards cc
                on cc.user_id = u.id
              where u.belongs_to = "ezpay"
                and cc.id is null )
```

But it throws the following error:

> #1093 - You can't specify target table 'users' for update in FROM clause

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use the `IN` operator because your SELECT statement can be transformed into a DELETE statement:

```
delete u.*
from users u
left join customers_cards cc
  on cc.user_id = u.id
where u.belongs_to = "ezpay"
  and cc.id is null;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can optionally use the negated `EXISTS` operator.

```
DELETE FROM users
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 
                 FROM customer_cards 
                 WHERE users.id = customer_cards.id)
  AND belongs_to = "ezpay"
```